# How to check if a child process has changed a specific file in WinAPI

Tags: c, file, winapi, createprocess

I have a program that opens an image in Paint using the CreateProcess WinAPI function, and I want to check if the user changed and edited the image while Paint was running.

How can I check if a file was changed by a child process?

Comment: [Obtaining Directory Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications) outlines, how to get notified about changes. You won't get information about the process that performed the changes.

Comment: Following the suggestion of @IInspectable, you can apply for change notification when running the process and remove the notification hook when process ends (if you don't care of user changes).

Comment: Do you know the name of "an image"? Then you can just use `stat` to get the d&t before and after. Note that while Paint is running, no changes are made to the file; a File Save operation is required.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping. Eventually I used @IInspectable 's solution. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @LiorLevin Glad to hear you got an solution. You can post an answer and accept it.